# How to match correctly only needed numbers type

Tags: regex

I have custom string:

```
Code: 12345
Price: $4900,50
```

And two regex for match numbers:

1. Regex for match numbers with fixed length: `/[0-9]{4,6}/mg`
2. Regex for match float numbers: `/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/mg`

1th regex must match only `12345` in this case but it's found also `4900` which is not needed.

**Demo 1th regex**: https://regex101.com/r/jnhsly/2

2th regex must much only float number from string. In this example string must found only `4900,50` but it's also found `12345` which is not needed result.

**Demo 2th regex**: https://regex101.com/r/If9y6G/1

How I can find only needed results in both regex in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1 of integer numbers only, you may use this regex:

```
(?<![\d.,])\d{4,6}\b(?![.,]\d)
```

- `(?<![\d.,])`: Make sure that we don't have a digit or `,` or `.` at previous position
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `(?![.,]\d)`: Make sure that we don't have a `,` or `.` followed by a digit at next position

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/jnhsly/4)

For case 2 of float numbers, you may use this regex:

```
\d+[.,]\d+
```

There is no need to make `[.,]\d+` optional since you are only matching floating point numbers here.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/If9y6G/2)

Comment: @AndreasHunter `(?<![\d.,])\d{4,6}(?![\d.,])` is wrong because it does not match a 4 to 6 digit number that is, say, before a comma or dot: [`The flight # was 1234.`](https://regex101.com/r/dBrQqk/1)

Comment: Hmm then it might be: `(?<![.,])\b\d{4,6}\b(?![.,]\d)`

Comment: `(?<![\d.,])\d{4,6}\b(?![.,]\d)` will still fail if there is no whitespace between a comma and a valid number. I posted the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61108809/3832970)

Comment: Of course, there can always be more than one possible solutions of a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

To match int numbers containing 4 to 6 digits, you need to use

```
(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])\d{4,6}(?![,.]?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XoqsH/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately on the left
- `(?<!\d[.,])` - no digit and `.` or `,` is allowed immediately on the left
- `\d{4,6}` - four, five or six digits
- `(?![,.]?\d)` - no optional `,` or `.` and a digit allowed immediately on the right.

The `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` pattern matches either integer or float values because the non-capturing group is *optional* thanks to the `?` quantifier, remove it. The whole non-capturing group will be redundant then, that is why the pattern to match float values will become `\d+[.,]\d+`.